# XML to base64 using python

Tags: python, xml, base64

How to convert complete xml file to base64 string using python/ scala?

I have tried b64 module ,but it requires a string(bytes-like) to  be passed to it . But how to do that with ML given it's multiline structure and hierarchy.
Could anyone give an example on how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: XML is still a string.

Comment: *"but it requires a string(bytes-like)"* - don't `open('file.xml', 'r')`, do `open('file.xml', 'rb')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python solution:

```
import base64

# convert file content to base64 encoded string
with open("input.xml", "rb") as file:
    encoded = base64.encodebytes(file.read()).decode("utf-8")

# output base64 content    
print(encoded)

decoded = base64.decodebytes(encoded.encode('utf-8'))

# write decoded base64 content to file
with open("output.xml", "wb") as file:
    file.write(decoded)

# output decoded base64 content
print(decoded.decode('utf-8'))
```